# deepstream is it possible to publish from my server, without opening a client connection in a browser

Tags: deepstream.io

I am somewhat confused in deepstream, is it possible to communicate to a client from my server? For example, is there any way to do something like this on a server? I am currently opening a client connection in browser that publishes to other clients. I would rather have the code below in my server.

```
var client = deepstream('localhost:6020').login()
var record = client.record.getRecord('new-record')

#Publish a message to all listeners of 'listen-channel' from my server?
record.set('listen-channel', 'message');
```

and then have clients listen:

```
record.subscribe('listen-channel', function(value) {
        console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just run it from a node process. Deepstream "clients" can be backend and frontend processes alike, permissioning is used to distuinguish between who can do what.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for double post, but do you think one node process can handle all the requests coming from every client if the client pool gets large to very large? Thanks.

Comment: Not really, but deepstream handles loadbalancing / distribution for you.

- For RPCs multiple processes can register as providers and deepstream will route traffic between them. Individual providers can also deny a request, prompting deepstream to ask the next one

- For records and events deepstream supports a feature called listening. Please find more about this here https://deepstream.io/tutorials/core/datasync-records/#listening